# How can I not just deny, but slow down requests from a crawler from a certain IP [nginx]

Tags: nginx

I have an overbearing and unauthorized crawler trying to crawl my website at very high request rates. I denied the IP address in my nginx.conf when I saw this, but then a few weeks later I saw the same crawler (it followed the same crawling pattern) coming from another IP address.

I would like to fight back not just by sending back an immediate 403 but by also by slowing down the response time, or something equally inconvenient and frustrating for the programmer behind this crawler. Any suggestions?

I would like to manually target just this crawler. I've tried the nginx limit_req_zone, but it's too tricky to configure in a way that does not affect valid requests.